# Know when app data from Application Manager is deleted

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to have an event that is called at the moment when the user of the phone has clicked 'Clear Data' in the 'Application Manager'. Is there a way to do that?

I need to know that because I got a database that holds very important information and I need to know when that information is deleted. I tried to look for database events for that and even events for data deletion with no luck.

Comment: Always check before you access the database if it's empty? Then you know that the user deleted it? You can run a service for that or just do the check on for instance onResume?

Comment: if i am correct, when user click Clear Data from AppMan, then the application get Force Closed first, so even if you have such event detector you will not be able to use it, i would go with @David Olsson suggestion.

Comment: The only way to protect 'very important information' in the ordinary Android application is not to hold any important information on the device. You need to employ the server for persisting important data. Android doesn't have any mechanisms for securing data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event.

The first opportunity to detect this is when your app is started next.
(If you're using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, your `onCreate` method will get called.)
However, there is no guarantee that the user will actually use your app again.